# Add columns of same email id in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a table which has participant details

```
 id     name    email         level_id    tournament_id
-------------------------------------------------------
20061   ABC    abc@gmail.com      1          1
20062   xyz    xyz@gmail.com      1          1
20063   ABC    abc@gmail.com      2          1            
20065   xyz    xyz@gmail.com      2          1
```

and another table LevelScore

```
    id      participant_id  level_id     score     
    -----------------------------------------------------
     1      20061               1        20
     2      20062               2        30 
     3      20063               3        10
     4      20061               4        30
     5      20065               5        50
```

I want to add scores of same participants at different level, for eg: `participant_id = 20061 &  participant_id = 20063` are same participants participanting at different levels and i know that because they have same email.

Now i want to compute total score of participant i.e `participant_score_level_1+participant_score_level_2+participant_score_level_3+participant_score_level_4 = Total score`

How can i do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `participant.group(:email)` for grouping the records according to the e-mail.

Answer (score 0):

Try `SELECT id, name, email, SUM(score) as score FROM participants GROUP BY email;`. Then you can use result of the query to populate the new table.

Answer (score 0):

You can group_by on email and in same query you can find sum of score also like below :

```
@participants = Participant.group(:email).select(:email, "SUM(score) as new_score")
```

Now When you try to create new table with unique email and sum of square you can do it like this :

@participants = Participant.group(:email).select(:email, "SUM(score) as new_score")

```
@participants.each do |participant|
  Model.create(:email => participant.email, :sum_score => participant.new_score)
end
```

Comment: This solution is not going to work on a relatively large database. Using raw sql will be on many orders of magnitude faster. Also please note that you probably don't want to run all this model's callbacks